# Why does this dereference of a DataRow null value not throw an exception?

Tags: c#, ado.net

Could you please look on the code below and say why this code doesn't throw an exception when the column value is null?

```
DataTable table = new DataTable();
table.Columns.Add("PreviewHtml");

table.Rows.Add(new object[] { "aksdhaskldh" });
table.Rows.Add(new object[] { "129836 128o tagjk 1782 3" });
table.Rows.Add(new object[] { null });
table.Rows.Add(new object[] { "1278o36 " });


foreach (DataRow r in table.Rows)
{
     Console.WriteLine(r["PreviewHtml"].ToString());
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's because [`DBNull.ToString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zkbzs85t%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) returns an empty string.

DataColumn's [`AllowDBNull`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.allowdbnull.aspx) property is set to true by default, otherwise you could not add `null` values.

`Null` values are converted to [`DBNull.Value`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3e77ezy5), [AutoIncrement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.autoincrement.aspx) columns are also incremented when `null` is passed.

Comment: In other words, `r["PreviewHtml"]` isn't `null`, even though `null` was what was added. I suppose that can be a bit confusing.

Comment: @Vytalyi because you expected `DBNull.ToString()` to throw an exception? :)